# How read value from result of httpClient.GetStringAsync?

Tags: c#, json

I did following coding & getting it's result in res variable.

```
 var res = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"{requestAdresschk}?$filter=DocDtls_No eq '99' & DocDtls_Type eq '" + oDocDtls_Type + "' & DocDtls_Dt eq '" + oDocDtls_Dt + "'  &$select=Oid");
```

I'm getting the below response:

```
"{{  "@odata.context": "https://test.smarts.com/api/odata/$metadata#Transation_Dtls(Oid)",  "value": [    {      "Oid": 26    }  ]}}"
```

Now I want to read whether that value contains data or not.. how can I read it?

Comment: I think JSON value isn't valid from your response

Comment: what about using Odata client? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/getting-started